# Использование функции одного класса в теле другого (Kivy, Python)

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

**Всем доброго!**
Мне нужно использовать функцию из класса **DepartureScreen** в теле класса **Date_Label**
Можете подсказать, как это сделать?

```
class Date_Label(Label):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Date_Label, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.cur_touch_pos = 0
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        self.cur_touch_pos = touch.x
    return super().on_touch_down(touch)
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        global cur_date
        if touch.x < self.cur_touch_pos:
            one_day = timedelta(1)
            cur_date = cur_date - one_day
            self.parent.ids.date_lbl.text = cur_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
            #self.text = cur_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
        elif touch.x > self.cur_touch_pos:
            one_day = timedelta(1)
            cur_date = cur_date + one_day
            self.text = cur_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
        else:
            print('Просто нажал!')
    return super().on_touch_up(touch)

class Departure_Table(MDDataTable):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.size_hint_x = None
    self.size_hint_y = None
    self.pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}
    self.height = 500
    self.width = 900
    #self.shadow_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)       

class DepartureScreen(Screen):
def __init__(self, **kw):
    super().__init__(**kw)
    global cur_date
    self.dep_table = Departure_Table()
    #cur_date = date.today().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
    self.ids.date_lbl.text = str(cur_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))
    self.load_dep_trains_data()
    
def load_dep_trains_data(self):
    self.ids.dep_table_rl.clear_widgets()
    self.ids.dep_table_rl.add_widget(Departure_Table(column_data = [('№ Поезда', 50), ('Прибытие', 50), ('Отправление', 50)]))

class MainApp(MDApp):
def build(self):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name = 'main_screen'))
    sm.add_widget(DepartureScreen(name = 'departure_screen'))
    Builder.load_file('main.kv')
    return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
MainApp().run()
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А унаследовать или создать объект класса вам не подходит?

Comment: Amgarak, подходит все, что будет работать. Потому что, все, что пробовал я, не работало