# Как использовать функции одного класса в теле другого?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

**Всем доброго!**
Мне нужно использовать функцию из класса **DepartureScreen** в теле класса **Date_Label**
Можете подсказать, как это сделать?

```
class Date_Label(Label):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.cur_touch_pos = 0
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        self.cur_touch_pos = touch.x
    return super().on_touch_down(touch)
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        global cur_date
        if touch.x < self.cur_touch_pos:
            one_day = timedelta(1)
            cur_date = cur_date - one_day
            self.text = cur_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
        elif touch.x > self.cur_touch_pos:
            one_day = timedelta(1)
            cur_date = cur_date + one_day
            self.text = cur_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
        else:
            print('Просто нажал!')
    return super().on_touch_up(touch)       

class DepartureScreen(Screen):
def __init__(self, **kw):
    super().__init__(**kw)
    global cur_date
    #cur_date = date.today().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
    self.ids.date_lbl.text = str(cur_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))
    #self.load_dep_trains_data()
    
def load_dep_trains_data(self):
    global cur_date
    self.ids.dep_table_gl.clear_widgets()
    #self.ids.dep_table_rl.add_widget(Departure_Table(column_data = [('№ Поезда', 50), ('Прибытие', 50), ('Отправление', 50)]))
    chosen_date = self.ids.date_lbl.text
    table_name = 'trains_' + chosen_date[0:2] + '_' + chosen_date[3:5] + '_' + chosen_date[6:11]
    conn = sqlite3.connect('train_dep_db.db')
    curs = conn.cursor()
    try:
        curs.execute('SELECT * FROM trains_29_02_2024')
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        if str(error) == 'no such table: trains_29_02_2024':
            print('Ошибка SQL: ' + str(error))
            print('Такой таблицы не существует!')
    conn.commit()
    curs.close()
    conn.close()
```

**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: Для этого нужно в экземпляр класса `Date_Label` как-то передать экземпляр класса `DepartureScreen`. Можно его передать при инициализации класса `Date_Label`, а можно при вызове какого-то его метода параметром этого метода.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Использование функции одного класса в теле другого (Kivy, Python)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1569402/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-kivy-python)

Comment: CrazyElf, я понял о чем вы. И даже пробовал это, но, к сожалению, ничего не получалось. Ошибок не было, но функция не работала. Можете приложить пример кода, если не трудно.

Comment: Лучше покажите ваши попытки )  Существенно знать, как вы инициализируете классы и вызываете их функции.

Comment: @CrazyElf В теле **DateLabel** писал так:
`self.dep_screen = DepartureScreen()` потом объявлял функцию
`self.dep_screen.load_dep_trains_data()`

Comment: Помощи я так понимаю я не получу здесь